# Using XSLT to compare two nodes and emit XML containing attribute indicating whether value was updated, added, or deleted

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

Been programming front-end languages for a long time and I rarely encounter `XSLT` on a project.  Well, here it is...  We currently have some functions in our XSLT file that are comparing nodes and emitting XML that contains something like `previousValue="Old value"`.  This feature helps our users understand what changed when viewing the form.

Looking at the XML (below), I need to compare `<ns1:OtherEducationTypeDesc>` and emit XML correctly that states what the old value was.

**I need it to look something like:**

```
<EducationTypes>
    <EducationType Code="11">Engineering</EducationType>
    <EducationType Code="12" Value="New Value" PrevValue="Old Value">Other</EducationType>
</EducationTypes>
```

I tried to give as much information as possible but if you need anything else, let me know!  Any assistance is appreciated!!  Thanks!!

---

### XSLT

```
<EducationTypes xmlns="omitted">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$has-updates">
      <!--Get unchanged nodes-->
      <xsl:variable name="unchanged-nodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="intersection">
          <xsl:with-param name="nodes1" select="$educationType-nodes[1]/ns1:Code"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="nodes2" select="$educationType-nodes[last()]/ns1:Code"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:call-template name="education-codes">
        <xsl:with-param name="node-set" select="msxsl:node-set($unchanged-nodes)/ns1:Code"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="otherText" select="$educationType-nodes[last()]/ancestor::ns1:ProgramInfo/ns1:OtherEducationTypeDesc"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

      <!--Get added nodes-->
      <xsl:variable name="added-nodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="difference">
          <xsl:with-param name="nodes1" select="$educationType-nodes[last()]/ns1:Code"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="nodes2" select="$educationType-nodes[1]/ns1:Code"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:call-template name="education-codes">
        <xsl:with-param name="node-set" select="msxsl:node-set($added-nodes)/ns1:Code"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="otherText" select="$educationType-nodes[last()]/ancestor::ns1:ProgramInfo/ns1:OtherEducationTypeDesc"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="status" select="'added'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

      <!--Get deleted nodes-->
      <xsl:variable name="deleted-nodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="difference">
          <xsl:with-param name="nodes1" select="$educationType-nodes[1]/ns1:Code"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="nodes2" select="$educationType-nodes[last()]/ns1:Code"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:call-template name="education-codes">
        <xsl:with-param name="node-set" select="msxsl:node-set($deleted-nodes)/ns1:Code"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="otherText" select="$educationType-nodes[last()]/ancestor::ns1:ProgramInfo/ns1:OtherEducationTypeDesc"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="status" select="'deleted'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="education-codes">
        <xsl:with-param name="node-set" select="$educationType-nodes/ns1:Code" />
        <xsl:with-param name="otherText" select="$educationType-nodes/ancestor::ns1:ProgramInfo/ns1:OtherEducationTypeDesc"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</EducationTypes>
```

---

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ns1:ProgramInfo>
  <ns1:RecognizedDegrees>false</ns1:RecognizedDegrees>
    <ns1:EducationCodes>
      <ns1:Code>01</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>02</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>09</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>10</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>12</ns1:Code>
    </ns1:EducationCodes>
    <ns1:OtherEducationTypeDesc>Old Description</ns1:OtherEducationTypeDesc>
    <ns1:DegreeCodes>
      <ns1:Code>03</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>06</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>07</ns1:Code>
    </ns1:DegreeCodes>
    <ns1:OtherDegreeDesc></ns1:OtherDegreeDesc>
    <ns1:EducationLevels>
      <ns1:Code>08</ns1:Code>
    </ns1:EducationLevels>
    <ns1:OtherEducationLevelDesc></ns1:OtherEducationLevelDesc>
</ns1:ProgramInfo>

<ns1:ProgramInfo>
    <ns1:RecognizedDegrees>false</ns1:RecognizedDegrees>
    <ns1:EducationCodes>
      <ns1:Code>01</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>02</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>09</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>10</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>12</ns1:Code>
    </ns1:EducationCodes>
    <ns1:OtherEducationTypeDesc>New Description</ns1:OtherEducationTypeDesc>
    <ns1:DegreeCodes>
      <ns1:Code>03</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>06</ns1:Code>
      <ns1:Code>07</ns1:Code>
    </ns1:DegreeCodes>
    <ns1:OtherDegreeDesc></ns1:OtherDegreeDesc>
    <ns1:EducationLevels>
      <ns1:Code>08</ns1:Code>
    </ns1:EducationLevels>
    <ns1:OtherEducationLevelDesc></ns1:OtherEducationLevelDesc>
  </ns1:ProgramInfo>
```

Comment: It is not clear to me how your output and your XML sample relate. Where do `Value` and `PrevValue` come from? Why are codes 11 and 12 in the output, while the others are not? Also, your XSLT code is not complete. It uses variables and templates that are defined elsewhere, so it is not entirely clear how it works.

Comment: And besides, where does the 11, the “Engineering” and the “Other” come from? I don't see them in the xml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend XMLUnit instead. XMLUnit is designed to compare xmls - http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/. I have personally used XMLUNit for comparing large (~10-20MB) xmls rather than using XSLT.

I have put together an ANT wrapper around XMLUNit so that directories of xmls can be compared and an CSV output is created - https://github.com/parj/AddOnJavaAntTasks/tree/master/org.pm.xml.AntXMLUnit

The jar file - https://github.com/parj/AddOnJavaAntTasks/downloads

Comment: Just going to give it to you brother.